# assigning variable to each output of lapply

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I'm trying to use lapply on my set of variables but I want the output as separate variables. For example.

```
df <- list(var1,var2,var3,var4)
di <- function(x) {diff(x)
difference <- lapply(df,di)
```

but this gives me a list of 4 items. but I want this result as x1,x2,x3,x4.
Is it possible to get this ?
Sorry for not being able to explain enough.

Comment: Try `list2env(setNames(difference, paste0('x', 1:4)), envir=.GlobalEnv)`, but it is better to have this in a `list` rather than as separate objects in the global environment.

Comment: Thankyou so much. Solved my problem but because I have to import my results into a tabular form so I had to covert the items of list in separate variables. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong tool for your goal.  The `lapply` function stores output in a list.  As akrun shows, you can coerce the results from the `lapply` into separate 4 separate objects, `x1`,`x2`,`x3`,`x4`.

A tool that will better suit your goal is a for loop.  For example,

```
for(i in seq(1, length(df))){
    n <- paste0("x",i)
    assign(n, diff(df[[i]]))
}
```

That all being said, your ultimate goal is a bit dubious.  I would recommend that you save the results in a list or matrix, especially if you are new to R.  By including all the results in a list or matrix you can continue to use functions like `lapply` and `sapply` to manipulate your results.

Answer (score 0):

You should just assing it again:

```
df<- list(var1,var2,var3,var4) 
df[1:4]<-lapply(df[1:4], function(x) diff(x))
```